# How to program a spinning cursor in c++ on OSX?

Tags: c++, macos, console

I need a progress indicator in the form of a spinning cursor for a command line program. I read a couple of threads with the advice of using the backspace character \b to delete the last printed character. However, when using \b with cout on OSX, the result is some UTF-8 character (an upside-down question mark).

Does anyone know if there is a way to get this problem solved with standard c++ means?

Comment: You'll need to use some platform-specific functionality to do this.  Perhaps from a library like ncurses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [ncurses library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) for cross-platform terminal access. You csn make nice text-only UIs using this.

Comment: Thanks guys. Seems I don't get around using a library for the purposes. Ncurses it is.